# How to prevent external direct-link to files with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, bandwidth

I have this in my htaccess at the public_html folder of my file server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite.net/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|png|jpg|jar|sis|mp3|thm)$ - [F]
```

And I have lots of folders and files inside the mysite.net/files dir, which I want to prevent from being direct-downloaded from sites other than mysite.net. However the above rules don't seem to work despite I know that .htaccess file is enabled. In some cases it only blocks the images but no the files. Please tell me what's wrong with that script, or if I can use any other directive to prevent external sites from leeching my files constantly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does it help if you add ".*"?

```
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|jar|sis|mp3|thm)$ - [F]
```

Also, your line:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/*
```

means (at the end) "a slash zero or more times". You might try:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/.*
```

which means "a slash then any character zero or more times".

**Edit**: Some of your files may be named with uppercase extensions. You might try:

```
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|png|jpg|jar|sis|mp3|thm)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: No, that didn't solve the problem, it seems there's something else wrong in that config. :(